# How to make a protocol extend another protocol and provide default implementation for it in Swift?

Tags: swift

I have a BinarySearchTree protocol and want to make all implementations of it to conform to Sequence protocol. Since the traverse method is enough for iteration, I wanted to provide a default implementation for makeIterator method which is required by Sequence so that any implementation of BinarySearchTree becomes iterable without doing anything further. But compiler gives two errors:

- *Type 'BinarySearchTreeImp' does not conform to protocol 'BinarySearchTree'*
- *Type 'BinarySearchTreeImp' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'*

I have done a similar thing for LinkedList and it worked fine.

What is wrong here?

```swift
protocol BinarySearchTree: Sequence where Element == (Key, Value) {
    associatedtype Key: Comparable
    associatedtype Value

    func insert(key: Key, value: Value)

    func remove(key: Key) -> Value?

    func find(key: Key) -> Value?

    func findPredecessor(key: Key) -> (Key, Value)?

    func findSuccessor(key: Key) -> (Key, Value)?

    func min() -> (Key, Value)?

    func max() -> (Key, Value)?

    func removeMin() -> (Key, Value)?

    func removeMax() -> (Key, Value)?

    func traverse() -> AnySequence<(Key, Value)>

}

extension BinarySearchTree {
    func makeIterator() -> AnyIterator<(Self.Key, Self.Value)> {
        return traverse().makeIterator()
    }
}

fileprivate class BSTNode<Key:Comparable, Value> {
    let key: Key
    let value: Value

    var left: BSTNode<Key, Value>?
    var right: BSTNode<Key, Value>?
    unowned var parent: BSTNode<Key, Value>?

    var isLeaf: Bool {
        left == nil && right == nil
    }

    init(key: Key, value: Value){
        self.key = key
        self.value = value
    }


    func toTuple() -> (Key, Value) {
        return (self.key, self.value)
    }

    func min() -> BSTNode {
        guard let left = left else { return self }

        return left.min()
    }

    func max() -> BSTNode {
        guard let right = right else { return self }

        return right.max()
    }

    func find(key: Key) -> BSTNode? {
        if key == self.key {
            return self
        }

        if key < self.key {
            guard let left = left else { return nil }
            return left.find(key: key)
        }

        guard let right = right else { return nil }
        return right.find(key: key)
    }


    func findPredecessor() -> BSTNode? {
        if let left = left { return left.max() }

        var current = self
        while let parent = current.parent {
            if current === parent.right {
                return parent
            }
            current = parent
        }

        return nil
    }

    func findSuccessor() -> BSTNode? {
        if let right = right { return right.min() }

        var current = self
        while let parent = current.parent {
            if current === parent.left {
                return parent
            }
            current = parent
        }

        return nil
    }

    func insert(key: Key, value: Value) -> BSTNode {
        if key <= self.key {
            if let left = left {
                return left.insert(key: key, value: value)
            } else {
                left = BSTNode(key: key, value: value)
                left!.parent = self
                return left!
            }
        } else {
            if let right = right {
                return right.insert(key: key, value: value)
            } else {
                right = BSTNode(key: key, value: value)
                right!.parent = self
                return right!
            }
        }
    }

    func delete() {
        if isLeaf {
            promoteChild(nil)
            return
        }

        if left == nil {
            promoteChild(right)
            right = nil
            return
        }

        if right == nil {
            promoteChild(left)
            left = nil
            return
        }

        let successor = right!.min()
        assert(successor.parent != nil)

        successor.left = left

        if successor.parent === self {
            promoteChild(successor)
        } else {
            let successorsParent = successor.parent!
            promoteChild(successor)
            // successor must be left child unless it is right child of self
            successorsParent.left = nil
            successor.max().right = self.right
        }

        left = nil
        right = nil
    }

    private func promoteChild(_ child: BSTNode?) {
        guard let parent = parent else { return }

        child?.parent = parent
        if parent.left === self {
            parent.left = child
        } else {
            parent.right = child
        }

        self.parent = nil
    }

}

class BinarySearchTreeImp<Key: Comparable, Value> : BinarySearchTree {
    private var root: BSTNode<Key, Value>?

    init(){}

    func min() -> (Key, Value)? {
        return root?.min().toTuple()
    }

    func max() -> (Key, Value)? {
        return root?.max().toTuple()
    }

    func find(key: Key) -> Value? {
        return root?.find(key: key)?.value
    }

    func findPredecessor(key: Key) -> (Key, Value)? {
        return root?.find(key: key)?.findPredecessor()?.toTuple()
    }

    func findSuccessor(key: Key) -> (Key, Value)? {
        return root?.find(key: key)?.findSuccessor()?.toTuple()
    }

    func insert(key: Key, value: Value) {
        if let root = root {
            root.insert(key: key, value: value)
        } else {
            root = BSTNode(key: key, value: value)
        }
    }

    func remove(key: Key) -> Value? {
        guard let node = root?.find(key: key) else { return nil }

        let result = node.value
        node.delete()
        return result
    }

    func removeMin() -> (Key, Value)? {
        guard let node = root?.min() else {
            return nil
        }

        node.delete()
        return node.toTuple()
    }

    func removeMax() -> (Key, Value)? {
        guard let node = root?.max() else {
            return nil
        }

        node.delete()
        return node.toTuple()
    }

    func traverse() -> AnySequence<(Key, Value)> {
        return AnySequence { () -> AnyIterator<(Key, Value)> in
            var currentNode: BSTNode<Key, Value>? = self.root?.min()

            return AnyIterator {
                let result = currentNode?.toTuple()
                currentNode = currentNode?.findSuccessor()
                return result
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For clarity, a protocol doesn't conform to another protocol but it can inherit from a protocol. So in your case the `BinarySearchTree` protocol extends the `Sequence` protocol.

Comment: Yes, you are right. What I tried to mean is that it practically conforms by providing a default implementation. I'll edit it accordingly, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the `min()`/`max()` requirements:

```swift
func min() -> (Key, Value)?

func max() -> (Key, Value)?
```

If you comment them out, the code builds.

`Sequence` also exposes these two functions, however they are part of an extension available only if `Element` is `Comparable`, which is not your case, so not sure why it confuses the compiler.

Another workaround is to have `BinarySearchTreeImp` declare the `Iterator` typealias:

```swift
typealias Iterator = AnyIterator<(Key, Value)>
```

, this will also silence the compiler, however it's not clear for future conformances that this will need to be added to solve a semi-obscure compiler error message.